# How to display only author's name for the current post?

Tags: theme-development

I want to just show the author's name (unlinked to author archive).

I don't want to show the author's avatar.

I have used some plugins but I got failed.

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/) function:

```
the_author_meta( string $field = '', int|false $user_id = false )
```

You may provide `$field` which is of these values:

```
admin_color
aim
comment_shortcuts
description
display_name
first_name
ID
jabber
last_name
nickname
plugins_last_view
plugins_per_page
rich_editing
syntax_highlighting
user_activation_key
user_description
user_email
user_firstname
user_lastname
user_level
user_login
user_nicename
user_pass
user_registered
user_status
user_url
yim
```

and is [well documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/). In your case you may choose `display_name`.

Also you may provide the `$user_id`. If you don't provide it, it will be the current author's DB object (author of current post).

If you want to get the name for some string manipulation and not directly printing on the output, just use `get_the_author_meta()`.